# future package not accessible

Tags: python, python-3.x, future, h2o

I am having problems in using future package in h2o:

```
 base) usr@usr-X705UDR:~$ pip install future
        Requirement already satisfied: future in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (0.18.2)
        (base) usr@usr-X705UDR:~$ python
        Python 3.8.12 (default, Oct 12 2021, 13:49:34) 
        [GCC 7.5.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
        Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
        >>> import future
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
        ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'future'
        >>>
```

How to rectify this?

Comment: Isn't it `__future__`?

Comment: it should be `import __future__` not `import future` i guess.